# constant in query of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the code from stored procedure of SQL server. I have declared constant @other_db to use it in queries. For simple queries i am able to do as mentioned below.

```
DECLARE @other_db VARCHAR(50)

    SET @other_db = 'BABMwork8_22_1210_0012'

    UPDATE BABMwork8_22_1210_0012.dbo.concessions   SET double_ones = '' WHERE double_ones = 'Yes'  

    EXEC('UPDATE @other_db.dbo.concessions SET double_ones = '+''+' WHERE double_ones = '+'Yes')
```

But for the query mentioned below, i want to use constant @other_db to replace the value of BABMwork8_22_1210_0012.

```
UPDATE concessions SET double_ones = 'Yes'
                   WHERE (concession IN(SELECT concession FROM BABMwork8_22_1210_0012.dbo.concessions WHERE
                                        (manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) AND 
                                        (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL)) 
                          OR concession IN(SELECT Concession FROM BABMwork8_22_1210_0012.dbo.invoicing WHERE 
                                        (can_invoiced is NULL OR can_invoiced != 'No') AND
                                        (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL)))
                          AND (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL) 
                          AND (manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) AND
                               source!= 'PARK'
```

Eventhough i tried with EXEC it is getting complicated. I have couple of queries if there any simple method to use constant.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How will you be executing this query? If manually I think `sqlcmd` mode might help. http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/

Comment: @Martin - My front-end is PHP. On click of a button the stored procedure is called in the back ground.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL and `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` as you are doing then I think. There is no way the database name can be parameterised and there is no support for database synonyms (which might have helped if concurrency wasn't a concern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are couple of approaches for doing this.

You can define and fill temporary table at beginning and fill it with dynamic exec query result. Then later in t-sql you wrote, simply replace BABMwork8_22_1210_0012 with temp table name.

sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #BABMworkInv 
  (col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 int....)

INSERT #BABMworkInv
  EXEC ('select * from ' + @other_db + '.dbo.invoicing')

UPDATE concessions SET double_ones = 'Yes'
                   WHERE (concession IN(SELECT concession FROM #BABMworkInv WHERE
                                        (manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) AND 
                                        (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL)) 
                          OR concession IN(SELECT Concession FROM #BABMworkInv WHERE 
                                        (can_invoiced is NULL OR can_invoiced != 'No') AND
                                        (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL)))
                          AND (double_action = 'ok_invoice' OR double_action is NULL) 
                          AND (manuell_archive_delete! = 'Delete' OR  manuell_archive_delete IS NULL) AND
                               source!= 'PARK'
```

Second approach is to create function that will accept database name as parameter and return table result. Then you can use code like: `Select * from dbo.MyFunction(@other_db)`.

Comment: Thanku for ur reply. As suggested, to create temp tables and then dump the data. But i am using many tables from the other database, which results in lot of temp tables. Will that be performance issue or..?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: lucky, yes, you are right, that will for sure slow down your query. Other way i think is to use dynamic t-sql. Code will not look nice but result will be what you required.